# sub classing from enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

I've a `generic_connection`

```
class generic_connection: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<generic_connection>
```

Now I want to subclass it and create

```
class agent_connection: public generic_connection
```

does `agent_connection` need to derive from `boost::enable_shared_from_this<agent_connection>` again ?

Comment: Your "again" is misleading - `agent_connection` never derives from `esft<agent_connection>`, only from `esft<generic_connection>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to derieve again. But, this has some problems, for example you cannot do call like this

```
shared_from_this()->agent_connection__method()
```

or this

```
boost::bind(&agent_connection::method, shared_from_this())
```

To solve this, you should do templated inheritance:

```
template <typename T>
class generic_connection : 
        public boost::enable_shared_from_this<T> {
};

class agent_connection : public generic_connection< agent_connection > {
};
```

This makes `agent_connection` more complicated, but you wont need to cast `shared_ptr` any time you use it.

Answer (score 5):

No.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: even if I call `shared_from_this()` from `agent_connection` member function ?

Comment: @NeelBasu yes; `shared_from_this` works as expected in such polymorphic settings.

Comment: I have constructors protected, and a static `create()` which returns a `shared_ptr`. Now should I return a `shared_ptr` of `agent_connection` or `generic_connection` ?

Comment: This isn't quite the best answer I've ever seen, but it's definitely top 2.